# Guessing the answer in a multiple choice exam with negative marking.

Tags: probability

In a multiple-choice exam, there are four choices for each question. We are awarded $4$ marks for every correct answer, $0$ for leaving the question and $-1$ for every wrong answer. Let's say we know 90% of questions correctly, how many questions can we attempt by guessing, among the rest, to avoid getting less than what we would if we had left the rest? What I want to determine is, what is better leaving or guessing?

**My Attempt**
If we attempt $x$ questions, the probability of getting each one correct is $\dfrac{1}{4}$. So, we can get about $\dfrac{x}{4}$ correct answers and $\dfrac{3x}{4}$ wrong answers.
Hence, total marks $=4*\dfrac{x}{4}+(-1)*\dfrac{3x}{4}=x-\dfrac{3x}{4}=\dfrac{x}{4}$
According to this, we never go into negative. But, what if we get fewer correct answers than $\dfrac{x}{4}$? Is there any way to consider the probability instead of just supposing $1/4$th correct answers?
Let's say we answer $1/k$th questions correctly.
Then, total marks $=4*\dfrac{x}{k}+(-1)*x\left(1-\dfrac{1}{k}\right)=\dfrac{4x}{k}-x+\dfrac{x}{k}=\dfrac{5x}{k}-x>0\implies k<5$
This implies that we must get more than $1/5$th answers correct to get positive marks. But, how many questions are right out of guessed ones is not in our hands. So, this is not that useful.

Comment: I assume there are 4 possible choices for each question?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "avoiding" negative marks? Do you want to be absolutely sure to not get negative marks, or do you want some probability that you will not get negative marks?

Comment: To prevent people from randomly guessing, multiple-choice exams usually award $P=-1/(C-1)$ points to wrong answers where $C$ is the number of choices. If $P<-1/(C-1)$, attempt all questions randomly. If $P>-1/(C-1)$, leave all you don't know blank. Also, randomly selecting a choice increases your chances if you can eliminate any of the choices and thus has an impact on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very long Comment , It may aid Modelling the Scenario.

"What I want to determine is :
Which is better : leaving it unanswered or guessing the answer ?"

**[1]** When going with "Default Probabilities" (which you have calulated) , either the "Payoff for guessing 1 Question" is Positive or 0 or Negative. When "Payoff for guessing 1 Question" is Positive , it is Positive for all unanswered Questions , hence there is no limit on "How many questions can we attempt ...."
Answer (by guessing) more , Expect more Marks.

Likewise , when "Payoff" is Negative , we should not guess at all.
Answer (by guessing) more , Expect less Marks.

When "Payoff" is 0 , we can arbitrarily guess or skip each Question , with no change in Expected Marks.

In given Case , it is always good to guess , to Expect $N/4$ more Marks.

**[2]** The right way to see this is not with "Default Probabilities" , It is with "Customized Probabilities" , where my terminology is like this :
**[2A]** "Default Probabilities" : Exactly Same for all Candidates , with no further knowledge.
**[2B]** "Customized Probabilities" : Where Candidate has further knowledge :
**[Eg1]** Eliminating a Choice or 2 , to make the Probability $1/3$ or $1/2$.
**[Eg2]** Candidate can Correctly answer 30 Questions out of 100 , knowing that 40 is Minimum to Pass. There is no way to Pass , hence Candidate has to resort to guessing , without calculating the Probabilities.
**[Eg3]** Not entirely eliminating some Choices , but knowing that some answer is more like to to be Correct.
**[Eg4]** When Candidate can Correctly answer 83 Questions out of 100 , knowing that 80+ will give a better grade , while 79- will give slightly lesser grade , then guessing 4 Questions will be a risk.
**[Eg5]** When Candidate can Correctly answer 89 Questions out of 100 , knowing that 90+ will give the best grade , then guessing a Question or 2 will be better.

In general , these Examples all have the Commonality that Candidate knowing more (Candidate **Studying** more) is best option rather than guessing more.

Comment: My question is if you know most answers(let's say 90 %), then you should leave the rest or guess them blindly?

Comment: The last line of Point [1] , "In given Case , it is **always good to guess** , to Expect $N/4$ more Marks" means you should guess those Questions to Expect $[90+(10/4)]$ Correct Answers totally. Observation : In your Post , @Souparna , you did not mention this 90% Detail at all.

Comment: Yeah, added the detail now, thanks.

Comment: When you have 90% Correct , then guessing all the remaining 10% will not make you "go into negative" : Even if you are unlucky & get every guess wrong , then you will get ~~87% total. When you are lucky & you may get everything right , then you will get 100%. Over-all , you may get ~~91%. That is why I am re-iterating "In given Case , it is always good to guess , to Expect $N/4$ more Marks" !!

Comment: What I meant by negative was, not to get less than what you would if you had left all those questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you always guess you can interpret the points you get on question number $n$ as a random variable $X_n$ wich has value $4$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ and $-1$ with probaility $\frac{3}{4}$.
Hence the expectation of $X_n$ is $E[X_n]= 4\cdot \frac{1}{4} + (-1) \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$

If you leave the question blank you get the random variable $Y_n$, which always has value $0$.
Hence $E[Y_n]=0$.

So if you compare expactations "guessing" is the better option.

But your question was "How many questions can we attempt by guessing blindly to avoid going into negative marks?".
And if we guess $n$ questions we have probability $\frac{3}{4}^n$ of guessing all wrong and score $-n$ on those. Therefore we are allowed to guesse $n$ questions
if we have $n$ points safe already ( if you are sure you got $\frac{n}{4}$ question correct).
If you can not be sure about gaining any points yet, we can not guess any question without risking getting a negative score.